# Change all Post titles into [Title Case] format

Tags: title, wp-title

I have about 2000 post with the titles in the following format:

```
[i like apples]
```

I want make them:

```
[I Like Apples]
```

I used the [WP Title Case plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-title-case/), but the problem is that this plugin is only capitalizing the title of the post itself, so just `h1` looks normal but `<title>` in `<head>` is still not capitalized. I guess the real non-capitalized titles are being fetched from database.

Maybe there is a SQL script to capitalize the column in the table of the database or a php script to change the `<title>` in head into normal format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT: WP Title Hook**

Ok, so if you're using wp_title (which you probably are, it's default) that function should have two filters in it you could use.

The first one is wp_title_parts, which returns your title broken up into an array.

```
function wp_title_capitalize( $title_parts ) {

    // Only uppercases the words of the first element (should be the page title)
    $title_parts[0] = ucwords( $title_parts[0] );

    return $title_parts;

}
add_filter( 'wp_title_parts', 'wp_title_capitalize' );
```

OR if you're ok with running the uppercase filter on the whole thing, you can run it on wp_title

```
function wp_full_title_capitalize( $title, $sep, $seplocation ) {

    // Uppercases the entire title
    $title = ucwords( $title );

    return $title;

}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'wp_full_title_capitalize' );
```

The second answer is easier to understand, since it runs on the whole thing, but if your titles look like

```
About Us | COMPANY NAME
```

Then, you probably want to go with the first option.

As always, with hooks & filters, these go in functions.php of your theme.

**Old Answer (CSS ONLY)**

If you're only worried about the display, you can just apply

```
text-transform: capitalize;
```

to the CSS of your h1.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_text-transform&preval=capitalize

Comment: Good answer, Thank you, but as far as I know css is not working for <title> tag in <head>

Comment: Yeah, CSS won't affect that. Sorry, I read your question wrong. I'll edit the question with an addendum answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use wordpress hooks in functions.php  but as socki03 answered I think this is abit better

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'ucwords' );
```

I still believe this is abit overkill

```
function wp_full_title_capitalize( $title, $sep, $seplocation ) {

    // Uppercases the entire title
    $title = ucwords( $title );

    return $title;

}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'wp_full_title_capitalize' );
```

I can't comment his answer so i am leaving this as a answer :)

Comment: I'm going to be honest, I've never used straight up PHP functions in an add_filter scenario.  Upvoting for me learning something.  Love the simplicity.  Only reason I'd use mine is if you want a bit more control, or explanation.